# Include certificate chain in signed pay load in node.js

Tags: node.js, cryptography

We are having a unique requirement where in we have to include the signing certificate in signed pay load. I'm looking for equivalent of CmsSigner class of .NET where I will be able to add the signing certificate as well as certificate collection to and then sign the data with the same and also include these certificate collection in signed pay load. If some one knows of way to achieve this in Node. js. 
I have tried using the crypto module of Node.js for signing. Unfortunately it does not have the capability to include the signing certificate in the signed pay load.

So please help with your suggestions
Thanks and regards
Venkatesh